# React Native - Delete not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to make a delete request to my api where I will delete a specific item to my Flatlist once the user press/ taps the "X" button. I'm done with the UI, and so I continue to do the backend by following a tutorial on youtube, as I finish the backend code and polish my other codes in UI, I immediately run my app but my result is nothing.

When I check my nodemon it says; [image: nodemon_screen_shot]
And this will be the same output in my console.log

My question is, why it is not working properly? What 'am I missing?

Here's my code:

SendOrder.js (backend)

```
router.delete('/delete_order/:id',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    db.query('Delete from orders where order_id=?', req.params.id, function(error, rows, field) {
        if(!!error)console.log('error');
        else {
            console.log(rows);
            res.end('seccess delete');
        }
    })
});
```

Settlement.js

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {
    delete = () => {
        fetch('http://192.168.254.100:3307/SendOrder/delete_order/', {
            method: 'DELETE'
        }).then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData.rows)
        }).done();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                 <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress = { () => this.delete() }>
                      <Text style = {{ padding: 10 }}>X</Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: `http://192.168.254.100:3307/SendOrder/delete_order/` You are not sending an id in the request

Comment: @Tholle should it be like this sir; http://192.168.254.100:3307/SendOrder/delete_order/:id  ??